# How to allow standard, non-admin, Active Directory users access to Docker without making them sudoers?

Tags: active-directory, permissions, docker, root, groups

I have a compute server with users that authenticate over AD.

I want these users to be able to use Docker without making them sudoers.

The [official advice](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/) is to add users to the `docker` group, as "[w]hen the docker daemon starts, it makes the ownership of the Unix socket read/writable by the docker group." So users belonging to the group `docker` won't need to run commands with `sudo`.

I can't add an AD user to a local group though.

How can I let them use Docker CE as non-root without creating local accounts?

Comment: You do know that you can give (groups of) users very limited privileges in `sudo` ; you don't have to grant them unlimited access to run any command as root or any other user.  - Is setting up `/etc/sudoers` to only allow those users to run the `docker` command not sufficient?

Comment: @HBruijn yes, in my ingorance that is exactly my thinking. And I did not know that. Can you point me at how to get started with looking at a granular sudo setup?

Comment: In most distributions both  the `/etc/sudoers` configuration file and its manual page `man sudoers` will already contain quite a few examples on how to group commands and set up permissions for specific users or for groups of users to run only those commands. But in the most simple form: add a line `louis    ALL = (root) /usr/bin/docker` to allow your user to only run (as root) docker with `sudo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add your user to docker group explicitly in /etc/group
and specify the group in /etc/docker/daemon.json

/etc/group

```
docker:x:groupID:user
```

/etc/docker/daemon.json

```
{
  "live-restore": true,
  "group": "docker"
}
```

restart docker daemon

Comment: This requires to manually edit this file for every new user. This is rather tedious in a company where people come and go.

Answer (score 0):

Hi There to complement  what Louis said on Ubuntu I 
ran:
 visudo
and added the

Dockeruser ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/docker

This way the user Dockeruser can run docker  with sudo without even having to reenter the password:

Dockeruser@dockerserver:~# sudo docker ps

Comment: I don't like how this requires editing the sudoers file. Also requires having uses perform tasks they don't normally do (running sudo with docker). This solution does not scale either, what if I have to do this on 200 hosts? This is more of a workaround not a solution.